# Can't upload theme in wordpress hosted on AWS Linux AMI

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2

I followed [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-instance_linux.html) to install and setup lamp & wordprss on linux and wordpress is now installed and working fine, except that I can't seem to be able to upload a theme.

I gave the ownership of the "www" directory and its files to the apache user and the www group.

When I try to upload a theme I get this error:

```
Are you sure you want to do this?
Please try again
```

Also when I try to install a plugin it asks me for FTP credentials, which as I understand means that wordpress is unable to edit certain files in the directory.

According to the solutions I found online, I edited the limits in the php.ini file but I don't think that this is related to the issue as the upload takes a few seconds and I get the error once the upload is finished.

I know the issue is definitely related to permissions and access but I don't know how can I give wordpress permission to its directory?

I ran the `ls -la` command on my /var/www directory to know the current permissions and these are the results:

```
drwxrwsr-x  7 apache www  4096 Oct  7 03:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root   root 4096 Oct  7 03:49 ..
drwxrwsr-x  2 apache www  4096 Aug 13 23:52 cgi-bin
drwxrwsr-x  3 apache www  4096 Oct  7 03:49 error
drwxrwsr-x  5 apache www  4096 Oct  8 01:08 html
drwxrwsr-x  3 apache www  4096 Oct  7 03:49 icons
drwxrwsr-x  2 apache www  4096 Oct  7 03:49 noindex
```

Comment: Do you have FTP access for this?

Comment: @Sina no but I can make one. Why?

Comment: I was eager to see whether you can upload the themes through the FTP or not? You might bypass all these permission troubles by doing that. I once had a heavy theme that couldn't be uploaded, and FTP upload to the themes folder nailed it :)

Comment: @Sina I can do that but then i'll face the same issue when I need to upload any media or install any plugins. So I want to solve the issue by giving wordpress all the permissions it needs to upload/edit/delete but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: So in other words, you can't upload _anything_ at all, yeah? Again I would say get your hands on FTP mate, it might be the [file permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) too.